# Restrict the map from moving to other places than in Tile Overlay in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am searching since yesterday and i am not successful yet ,

I follow the step in http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay.html

for implementing Tile Overlay and i could get that perfectly .

But the thing is that i dont want the google maps to be navigated to the some other place than the images placed in the tile overlay .

Below is the code i used for doing this ,

```
if (mMap == null) 
{
  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps)).getMap();

  GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener  ccl = new OnCameraChangeListener() 
  {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition camerapos) {
        if(camerapos.zoom < 15 && camerapos.zoom > 11)  
        {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(60.101732 , 10.537432), 11f);  
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);                                        //59.805140, 10.036319
            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }

        if(camerapos.target.longitude > 10.892347 )  
        {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(60.101732 , 10.537432), 11f); 
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);                                       //59.805140, 10.036319

            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }

        if(camerapos.target.longitude < 10.23461356 )  
        {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(60.101732 , 10.537432), 11f); 
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);                                       //59.805140, 10.036319

            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }

        if(camerapos.target.latitude > 60.35452469 ) 
        {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(60.101732 , 10.537432), 11f);  
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);                                       //59.805140, 10.036319
            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }

        if(camerapos.target.latitude < 59.9084916 )  
        {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(60.101732 , 10.537432), 11f);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);                                       
            mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }
  }
 };
 mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(ccl);
```

But it is for time being i used and also it is not accurate . When i go to the extreme end and zoom i could see the original google map there (in grey grid - since i disabled the map ).

Is there any other way that i could try , so that the map should show ( zoom in / zoom out ) only the places for which the tile overlay is set to .

Comment: I have couple of things in mind that will give you what you want but I am stuck in little technicality. Can you please tell me exactly what kind of geography are you trying to show? A country, is it? Also, you do not want the empty grid at all in your mapview or you just want to restrict the empty regions in UI?

Comment: This is a good reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views.